# Make a Boolean do something else if true for a certain time

Tags: java, boolean, key, action, duration

im working on a project right now and the boolean im using `active` can either print "active" while the action is still being preformed (such as a key is being held down) or "not active". I am trying to make it so that if the boolean `active` is true for more than 2 secs at a time (resets when it's not active anymore" it does something else.

**Code:**

```
    public void upWasPerformed(boolean active) {//method thanks to MadProgrammer
        if (active){
            System.out.println("active");
        }
        else if (!active){
            System.out.println("not active");
        }
        /**
         *else if active is true for more than 2 secs, print "active for 2 secs"
         *else if active is true for more than 4 secs, print "active for 4 secs"
         *etc.
         */
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What classes did you look at?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be using boolean == true or boolean != true, using if(boolean) checks if the boolean is true, and using if(!boolean) checks if the boolean is false.

Comment: Capture the time at which `active` first becomes true (`System. currentTimeMillis`), when you check the active state, check the current time compared to the "active" time and see if the difference is >= 20000